How to use llm model from Hugging Face in Convai for Unreal Engine?
I am trying to implement a custom LLM model form Hugging Face in Convai plugin used in Unreal Engine.
Convai does have its own model but it does not support the language i need.
Is there any ways of embedding your model from outside?
Thanks!
